# Logic Apps workflow definition language - aggregation?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I have several objects:

```
{
"product":"bike",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-05T00:00:00"
},
{
"product":"flowers",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-05T00:00:00"
},
{
"product":"balls",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-10T00:00:00"
},
{
"product":"phones",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-10T00:00:00"
},
{
"product":"microphones",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-08T00:00:00"
},
{
"product":"monitors",
"ExpectedDeliveryDate": "2018-11-08T00:00:00"
},
```

I want a list of distinct dates, removing duplicated. How can I extract the three unique dates here

- 2018-11-05T00:00:00
- 2018-11-10T00:00:00
- 2018-11-08T00:00:00

Using Workflow expressions?

Comment: Any process now? Please feel free to let me know if you still have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Workflow expressions?

It seems that **it's hard to use workflow expression to achieve it**. You want to get the `ExpectedDeliveryDate` property and deduplicate it if it is duplicate.

However, **there is no attribute like distinct in workflow expression**, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#workflow-functions).

So, I suggest that you could use Azure function to achieve your logic and **call azure function in logic app**. Here is a similar [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-call-azure-function-in-logic-apps/) you could refer to.